# Managing user defined types across files

Tags: python

**Is there a general rule of thumb to follow with creating custom types to use across different files?**

I'm currently trying to use my custom types across different modules. I would much rather have a single source of truth for custom types that need to be re-used.

### Use case

I'm integrating with multiple webservices from the same provider for our item management system.

The catch here is that some of the webservices use shared properties like a (**store number**, **service area**, **action code** etc.). I've made custom types to restrict entries of invalid property values. ie:

```py
ActionCodes = typing.Union[
   typing.Literal["Add", "Update", "Delete"]
]
```

Which would be used like this in a **pydantic model**

```py
class ItemInfo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    ActionCode: ActionCodes = "Update"
    OrgUnitNum: int = 0
    ItemNum: int
    PluNum: int
    PluDescription: str
    ServiceAreaNum: ServiceAreaNumber
```

### Edits

"I keep ending up in this senario where I want to use a type but that type is already imported to a previous file (causing a circular import)."

As I've seen asked yes I have to import modules into my types.py file. Specifically from my **models/** directory.

An example would be in need `types.py` in `entity_models.py` but also need `types.py` in `entity_models.py` and other files like `update_prices.py`.

**types.py**

```py
# models
import models.models as models
import models.entity_models as entity_models

# typing
import typing


# freshiq list definitions
FreshIQPriceList = typing.List[entity_models.FreshIQPrices]
FreshIQPluList = typing.List[entity_models.FreshIQScalePlus]
FreshIQItemList = typing.List[entity_models.FreshIQItem]

# freshiq dict definitions
FreshIQPluDict = typing.Dict[str, entity_models.FreshIQScalePlus]
```

**update_prices.py**

```py
# config
from config.databases import SALES
from config import mail as mail_config
from config import freshiq

# classes
from classes.do_entity_search import DoEntitySearch

# utility functions
from utils.job_runner import job_runner
from utils import mail
from utils import types as T

# models
from models import entity_models
from models import models

# python modyules
from datetime import date, timedelta
import logging
```

**entity_models.py**

```py
# config
from config import freshiq
from config import env

# types
from utils import types as T

# pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

# python modules
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Union, Literal, Any
```

### Working directory

```
 - classes/
   - do_entity_search.py (uses types)
   - webservice.py (uses types)
   - item_webservice.py (uses types)
 - config/
   - databases.py
   - env.py
   - webservice_config.py (uses types)
 - models/
   - entity_models.py (uses types)
   - item_models.py (uses types)
 - utils/
   - types.py (custom types)
 - update_prices.py (runnable script)
 - import_items.py (runnable script)
```

### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\janrico\Documents\GitHub\FreshIQ\jobs\update_prices.py", line 7, in <module>
    from classes.do_entity_search import DoEntitySearch
  File "C:\Users\janrico\Documents\GitHub\FreshIQ\jobs\classes\do_entity_search.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils.functools import update_item, insert_item, create_itemcode_map
  File "C:\Users\janrico\Documents\GitHub\FreshIQ\jobs\utils\functools.py", line 7, in <module>
    from models import entity_models
  File "C:\Users\janrico\Documents\GitHub\FreshIQ\jobs\models\entity_models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils import types as T
  File "C:\Users\janrico\Documents\GitHub\FreshIQ\jobs\utils\types.py", line 10, in <module>
    FreshIQPriceList = typing.List[entity_models.FreshIQPrices]
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'models.entity_models' has no attribute 'FreshIQPrices' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

### My Solution (although not preferred)

I ended up moving relevant types that used `enity_models` into the `entity_models.py` file. This seems to work as expected but it defeats the purpose of having a single source of truth for types.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you store all of your types in one file `types.py`, then I would not expect circular imports (unless you are importing parts of your package into `types.py`)

Comment: Please make a [mre] including some code that causes the error. It also doesn't hurt to include the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: "I keep ending up in this senario where I want to use a type but that type is already imported to a previous file (causing a circular import)." That doesn't make sense given what you've provided above. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I have added more information to the question as suggested in the comments along with the full error message

Comment: OK, it looks like your question is answerable now, but it'd still help to make your example minimal and reproducible. To start, you don't need to include all four `FreshIQ*` when one would suffice, and `FreshIQPrices` is never defined in `entity_models`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, I just ran into this problem. I believe the issue is the name of the file - you cannot name it `types.py` and import it. When importing, it imports a different file instead of your newly created `types.py` (it imports this [file](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/types.html)). If you name it something else, perhaps `Types.py`, it should import nicely.